# Pressure vessel analysis of transversely isotropic multilayer material

Tags: pressure, material-science, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

Suppose I have a transversely isotropic, hyperelastic material with known strain energy that is a fibrous composite. I am interested in an explicit formula for the displacements (so I can get the stress and strain tensors) for a pressure vessel made of such a material, *but* where the local fiber direction (i.e. axis of transverse isotropy) varies smoothly as a function of the radial direction ($f(r):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ is $C^\infty$).

For example, something like [Roy, 1991, "Strength analysis and design of multilayered thick composite spherical pressure vessels"](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a236266.pdf) has (somewhat) explicit formulas. But note that my material does not change throughout the wall, except for the continuously varying local direction of anisotropy. Also, I do not have discrete layers and my material is non-linearly elastic.

This sounds like a problem for multilayer, laminar composites, but I do not have discrete layers, which those analyses that I have seen so far tend to assume (and reasonably so, since I am considering a model of a biological tissue, rather than something engineering oriented). I could also assume that there are a finite number of layers, but I don't think that would be analytically tractable, and my goal is to do some variational analysis over the space of functions $f$.

If it makes it easier, it would also suffice to have some analysis of a thick-walled "plate" with the properties above or even to assume linear elasticity.

Mainly, I am looking for literature (since, at least for me, this is not so trivial). But any help would be appreciated. Even better words to search for would be nice, since I am relatively new to continuum mechanics.